React Native Firebase Firestore ios build errors on terminal xcodebuild exited with error code 65. on xcode FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found
after i install firebase and firestore. i tried to rebuiled  the app its working on android well but when i try to build the ios the build stuck (i have in the folder the google-service.json).
i tried also from xcode same problem
in my xcode im getting this error
FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found
and in the terminal im getting
error Failed to build ios project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '65'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'Gb.xcworkspace'.
this is my packege.json
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^21.0.0",'''

this is my podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  # use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

end

pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseFirestoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true

target 'Gb' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'GbTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-    native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end

if i delete firebase and firestore the build on ios working

Try something like this -
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod ‘Firebase/Core’
pod ‘Firebase/Database’
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’


not working, same result
